# How do I organize my terraform resources to minimize change impact and the number of builds it takes to deploy something?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, cicd

So, I have a lot of resources I want to provision using Terraform. I want to automate the deployment, but I have trouble grouping resources together.

It is mostly backend APIs (both synchronous and asynchronous), a frontend app, and some additional code for asynchronous processing of events.

However, I want to minimize the change impact due to a `terraform apply`. But I also want to avoid the scenario where I have to manually create each and every resource. The sweet spot is that if I make a change to a API, only resources the API needs get provisioned.

For Terraform to completely capture the dependency graph, I will have to create a single module that contains all the resources for all the code I have.

But this goes against my minimizing the change impact principle.

I have tried coming up with the following. But I am not satisfied.

So, I split up all the resource in smaller modules based on what is needed for a given API or web app to execute. So, frontend will have its own tfstate file and each APIs will have their own tfstate file.

One problem with this is when two APIs share some resource. I thought I would further split the resources in to submodule. So if I have two APIs, A and B, I create a module with common resources, module A's resources and module B's resources.

And when I want to provision API A, I would run `terraform apply -target=moduleA -target=common`.

Another problem is when frontend needs to refer to API URLs. That is just one example where the . Having a single tfstate would have allowed me to inject these variables, but I can't do it anymore.

I did think of using `terraform_remote_state`, but I am not sure if that is a best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `terraform_remote_state` is a good and common practice - I would even recommend it for your use case.

Another thing you might want to be interested in is [Atlantis](https://www.runatlantis.io/) for running the CI/CD for Terraform - it is capable of detecting where the change is and what depends on that change, so that might be a perfect fit for your sweet spot.